# iOS - UITableViewCell change height depending on data cell holds

Tags: ios, twitter, uitableview

I have a `tableView` with each `cell` containing the username and tweet of a twitter user: http://postimg.org/image/5p8y9wh47/

But as you can see from the image it doesn't show the whole tweet of the user. how do i get it to show the whole tweet of the user and resize the table view cell as a whole?

I know i have to use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` but i don't know how to even start on that...

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ @%@", [tweet[@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"], [tweet[@"user"] objectForKey:@"screen_name"]];

cell.detailTextLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tweet[@"text"]];
```

how do i get the height of textLabel and detailTextLabel (with the whole tweet) and change the cell size accordingly?

## UPDATE

What i have been trying:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//get tweet data
NSDictionary *tweet = _userPosts[indexPath.row];

//create a string for the header - name (@username)
NSString *header = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ @%@", [tweet[@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"], [tweet[@"user"] objectForKey:@"screen_name"]];

NSString *tweetData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tweet[@"text"]];

CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f, MAXFLOAT);

CGSize labelSize = [header sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]} constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(_feedTableView.bounds.size.width, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right path to do this in `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Look in Apple's NSString UIKit Additions Reference to see how to get the size of your string:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893

You will want to use `– boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` to get the height of your username and tweet strings.

Comment: is it possible if you could help me out with that? Im trying but for some reason i just keep getting errors. I've added what I'm trying to the question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. I assume you are having issues with `sizeWithAttributes`. I'm not in front of a Mac at the moment, but I will post an example when I am later this morning.

Comment: Hey, sorry I'm still not at my Mac. However, looking at the code you posted you are calling `sizeWithAttributes: constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` which is not a method of NSString. You want `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` or `sizeWithAttributes:`